# Eclipse sirius cannot reload the diagram editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-sirius

I have the EMF model and created the Sirius project for that EMF model. When I run the application and select the created view point I get the diagram editor to drag and drop the features of the model to the editor and I save it. But when I tried to reload the application I get cannot load the part control exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.sirius.diagram.business.internal.experimental.sync.DDiagramSynchronizer.getAllMandatoriesAdditionalLayers(DDiagramSynchronizer.java:328)
```

Any solution for this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Better ask this in the [Sirius Forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=262)

Comment: did not get any solution from Sirius forum till now.. help me if anybody is aware of this problem.

Comment: Did you validate your viewpoint?

Comment: If I validate it  shows error in the viewpoint specification project (.odesign file).

Comment: This validation is showing error even for the basic family example also.

Comment: Should we customize the validation given by sirius